# Is there a statistically significant difference between two methods, which test should I use & am I violating random assumption?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, t-test, median

I collected data for every 2016 Republican primary that has available at least 3 polls, according to the polling data aggregated by RealClearPolitics.com. In a spreadsheet for each row which indicates a contest, there is column for the percentage won by the winner and the percentage won by the runnerup. There are three "forecasted values" each with two columns for both the winner and the runnerup, for the mean of the last 5 most recent polls for each primary, for the trimmed mean (25%, innerquartile) of the last 5 polls, and for the mean of the last 5 polls.

Basically, I want which measure of central tendency (mean, trimmed mean of 25%, median, in order of "robustness") which I collected data for had the least forecasting error in terms of symmetric percentage error between the margin between winner and runnerup and the forecasted error between the measure of center forecasted winner and the measure of center forecasted runnerup. The symmetric absolute percentage error formula is |((FORECASTEDMARGIN)-(ACTUALMARGIN)/(FORECASTEDMARGIN+ACTUALMARGIN))|*100 as a percentage, and this is calculated for each three types of central tendency for each primary. I used this to calculate the error, as a metric of accuracy where lower is better in terms of how much the forecast deviates form the  actual electoral margin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error

I can obviously see which measure of central tendency has a lower average of percentage error, and I currently do, but I would like to use a statistic to determine whether this is statistically significant, or the strength of the correlation. Which hypothesis test could I use? I thought about a T-test but would using all the available data of Republican primaries with more than 2 polls violate the randomness assumption of the sample (my three samples consisting of the percentage error of the margin, between the forecast and actual election results for each contest, each sample for each of the three measures of central tendency I gathered data for the last 5 most recent polls. Could the baseline could be the sample for the mean)?

I can share my data if you'd like, but in my opinion this is more of a methodology question. Thank you! I'm obviously a novice, and I appreciate this help. I have all the data already, I guess a more general verison of my question is: would taking most of the polls from the 2016 Republican primary violate the random assumption, in the sense that it cannot be applied to Republican primary populations in general? If this is true, how can I test for significance alternatively?